How to configure ports and ensure proper traffic flow in a Layer 2 switch snake test
I am trying to perform a Layer 2 switch test using a snake test. My topology is as follows:

There are two computers and four switch ports.

Port 1 and Port 2 are in VLAN 10.

Port 3 and Port 4 are in VLAN 20

PC1 is connected to Port 1, and PC2 is connected to Port 4.

Port 2 and Port 3 are connected via a physical Ethernet cable.


I’m unsure about a few things:
What modes should the ports be set to: access, trunk, or hybrid?
Given that Port 2 and Port 3 are connected via a physical cable, do I need to do anything else to ensure proper traffic flow between VLAN 10 and VLAN 20?
Any advice on what else I need to configure or check would be greatly appreciated!


all 4 ports should be set as access ports,
the idea behind the access port is that it removes the vlan tag in the OUT direction, and adds it in the IN direction. So it's safe to say, that the traffic while being >in< the cable connecting ports 2 and 3 has its vlan tags stripped,
looks to me that you're set, feel free to ask if you have any more questions.

Regards
Mike


What modes should the ports be set to: access, trunk, or hybrid?

Choose access if you just want a port that's "in VLAN XX". This configures one untagged VLAN and nothing more.
trunk and hybrid use tagged VLANs, where each packet carries its VLAN ID on the wire – what you'd use to create a multi-VLAN "trunk" connection between two switches. You don't want this in your test, however, as it would prevent you from "converting" VLAN 10 to VLAN 20 – the receiving port would see that the packet is tagged with ID 10.

Given that Port 2 and Port 3 are connected via a physical cable, do I need to do anything else to ensure proper traffic flow between VLAN 10 and VLAN 20?

You might need to disable Spanning Tree (STP, RSTP, MSTP) on those two ports, as the standard (non-Cisco) version works underneath VLANs so it will detect a loop between the two ports despite them being on different VLANs.
The same goes for manufacturer specific "Loop detect" functions that some switches have.

thanks a lot. I disabled spanning tree protocol for all ports, and ıt worked. Before this configuration some ports down.
